# How to handle "all" received push notifications when one is tapped in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I can get the FCM onResume method to be called when the user taps on one of the notifications.  But the other notifications all also have Data that I want the app to receive.

How can the app get the data of all other notifications that have been received while the app was in the background when the user taps any one of them?